# DrawLines over Image using graphics in compact framework

Tags: c#, image, graphics, compact-framework2.0

I have a picturebox control in which by using mouse down and mouse move events ,I am drawing a image using points and storing it in my database.
and in update mode I am retrieving the bytes and drawing an image in to the picture box control and now I am adding few lines more on the image but either I am getting newly added lines or the old image but i want both

```
  //rect is my picture box
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(rect.Width, rect.Height);
            // Create compatible graphics
            Graphics gxComp = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);

 //If i have a image 

           System.IO.MemoryStream memStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(TmpSign);
                    Bitmap im = new Bitmap(memStream);
```

Tmp is my byte array of my image

```
         gxComp.DrawLines(pen, _currentStroke.ToArray());
```

_currentStroke is the list of points.

Answer (score 0):

Creating the grahics of image and drawing lines on to that graphics object has solved my problem.

```
          //Ref with above Code
```

//Creating the graphics of the image if exists

```
      gxcomp=Graphics.FromImage(im);
```

and 
        //writing my new drawn points on to the graphics

```
       gxComp.DrawLines(pen, _currentStroke.ToArray());
```